# segmentation fault when using static variable

Tags: c, unix

```
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct passwd* Getpwnam_(const char* name)
{
        static struct passwd* passwd;

        while((passwd=getpwent())!=NULL)        /* get pw entry line by line */
        {
                if(strcmp(passwd->pw_name, name)==0)    /* find the same name */
                        return passwd;
        }

        if(passwd==NULL)        /* there is no matching name */
                return NULL;
}

int
main(void)
{
        printf("%ld %ld\n", (long)(Getpwnam_("root")->pw_uid), (long)(Getpwnam_("cho")->pw_uid));
}
```

On the above code, when I use main functions like:

```
printf("%ld\n", (long)(Getpwnam_("root")->pw_uid));
printf("%ld\n", (long)(Getpwnam_("cho")->pw_uid));
```

It is well operated. But, when I use one `printf()` with two `Getpwnam_()` as arguments, I get a segmentation fault. I think there's no problem in my code operation.

But, why this gives me an segmentation fault??

Comment: does user `cho` exisst on your system?

Comment: @fluter: Yes, sure

Comment: Are you sure that Getpwnam_() returns you non-NULL in both calls? I believe you should get NULL for the root password if you run your program as a non-root user

Comment: @Michael: Yse, the output is `0 \n 1000` when I use command below one, not above one` and I'm using root account.

Comment: Technically, you have a path out of your function without a `return`.  In practice, the only reason for escaping the loop is covered by the `if` condition, so it always returns a value, but the test is unnecessary and removing the test avoids having the compiler complain.

Comment: Why are you using `static` for `passwd` at all?  It provides no advantage.

Comment: Meaning you try to do the following: `struct passwd* p= 0; printf("%ld %ld\n", (long)(p->pw_uid);` It must crash

Comment: @sjsam: Sry, That was my mistake. I edited it.

Comment: @Michael: I edited my question to use one `%ld`. Sry for confusing.

Comment: @A.Cho : Thanks, I see the edit

Comment: @A.Cho It is not the format that is wrong. The problem is dereferencing 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewind he password database with `setpwent()` between the calls to `Getpwnam_()`.

Let's say your application calls `Getpwnam_("cho")` first. If in the database `"root"` is before `"cho"`, in the search in one point `getpwent()` will return `"root"` but your search will discard it as it's different from `"cho"`. Later on `getpwent()` will return `"cho"` which is the valid result.

If next your application calls `Getpwnam_("root")`, `getpwent()` will start returning entries from the point that was left on the last call, which in the database is beyond both `"root"` and `"cho"`. As `"root"` will not be returned anymore, the search will not get the result and you'll get a null pointer which crashes the program.

Comment: I found the problem. The reason why is that what atturri just said. When the first call of `Getpwnam_("cho")`, give right value. But w/o `endpwent()`or `setpwent()`.  The second call of `Getpwnam_()` will return NULL. So outputing NULL with `%ld` gives me an error

Comment: @atturri: Why `Getpwnam_()` call in each `printf()` reset the entry searching line?? I mean the two call of `Getpwnam_()` in one `printf()` is not reset entry searching line. I mean when first call of `Getpwnam_("cho")`, it will return value. But, after call of `Getpwnam_("root"`), it will return NULL value because of no entry for root below the`cho`. But, why each `printf()` call search the entry at the first which doesn't make segmentation fault?

Comment: @A.Cho Sorry I'm not sure I understand. You need to search the whole database from the start in each of your `while` loops in order to make sure that the user is found. You can rewind the database inside `Getpwnam_()`, or outside. And also note that the rest of the answers point out another problem you have with your code.

Comment: Sry, I got misunderstanding on my code. Nevermind what I said. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

One problem is that you're trying to keep two password entries live at the same time.  A subsequent call to `getpwent` may overwrite the previously returned info.  So you need to finish processing the returned info before calling `getpwent` again.  If necessary, make a copy of the fields that you need.

Also, there is no need to declare the pointer to be static, since you aren't returning its address.

(The other problem was mentioned by atturri, which is that you weren't rewinding to the beginning of the passwords with `setpwent` between calls.  This would have been clearer if the code had checked for a `NULL` return before attempting to reference the password fields.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is most likely related to the fact `getpwent` returns a pointer to a (possibly static) memory area which it manages. So basically when you get the return value you must use it BEFORE making another call to `getpwent`. Because the 2nd call could overwrite or even free the area returned to by the previous call.

From the man page:

> The return value may point to a static area, and may be overwritten
>          by subsequent calls to getpwent(), getpwnam(3), or getpwuid(3).  (Do
>          not pass the returned pointer to free(3).)

So two separate prints work, because you use the first one before the 2nd call. But putting both in the same print means the 2nd call invalidates the pointer returned by the 1st call, but then print tries to use both ponters. Even if you didn't get a seg fault, it would most likely not produce correct output for the first user.

Instead you will need to change your Getpwnam_ to copy the data you need into a freshly allocated object, and return a pointer to that. NOTE: The copying will need to be "recursive" if you want some of the strings too.